# Is there a way to use incremental machine learning with plpython3u in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, plpython, online-machine-learning

I'm working on a project where I need to use incremental machine learning to update a model based on new data. I'm using PostgreSQL as my database and plpython3u as my procedural language. I've been searching for a way to use incremental machine learning with plpython3u, but I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this.

Is there a way to use incremental machine learning with plpython3u in PostgreSQL?
If so, how can I do this?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "yes"; however, the second question is too broad since there are myriad possible approaches and the posts lacks sufficient details to narrow the options. Please see [ask].